# New HD has just died: any way to resurrect it?

Tags: hard-drive, storage, hard-drive-failure

I bought a brand new WD Blue 4TB hard drive, and decided to test it for a bit before actually starting to use it. I plugged it into an external USB3 dock, and ran HDDScan on it (the "read" test) for a few hours (I'm on Windows 7, by the way).

After testing about 70% of the drive, HDDScan started to show bad blocks. I stopped it and looked at the SMART data, but the "Reallocated sectors count" was at 0, so I thought that they would be the bad blocks that every drive has when manufactured and that come already pre-reallocated. I then tried to unplug the drive... and here the problems began.

I clicked on Windows "Eject device" to eject the external drive... and the HD started to make a clicking sound. Since Windows didn't eject it, I rebooted with the external USB dock (and the drive) turned off. Once I rebooted, I tried turning the USB dock on again. The drive started making the clicking sound again, but after a few seconds it stopped and Windows showed **again** the "Installing drivers" message, as if it was being plugged in the first time...

...but it didn't show up in Explorer, so I went into the Disk Manager. It said then that I had to initialize the drive (again, as if it was being plugged in the first time), but when I try to initialize it, it says "the operation could not be completed due to a I/O error).

So, my question is: RMA, or is there anything else I can do to revive this drive?

Comment: Sounds like the dock fried the drive.

Comment: You get the same errors outside the USB dock, when it's directly connected? If so, it just sounds broken, and being new it *should* be very easily exchanged/returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RMA.

(As Xen2050 noted, once you've eliminated the dock as the source of the problem).

If you could revive it, wouldn't you be worried about data loss on an "unreliable" hard drive?